# Maven processing ressources / replacing maven variables

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, web-applications, jboss7.x

I have a Java/Maven project for building a JBoss web application.
I am using the maven capability for filtering resources to build the live and the test version.

To get the idea:
I use maven variables which will be replaced in the building-process like the WAR-name in the pom.xml or the JDBC-path to the database, which should be used by the deployment (different DBs for production and test).

The problem I have is the following:
In the jboss-web.xml I need to set the Context-path for the deployment (live-version has the context-path '/', the test version should have the context-path '/test').
For the maven goal 'process-resources' the variables will be replaced properly, but for the goal 'package' the source-files (with the variable declaration) are used, which leads to errors.
How can I configure, that maven uses the processed resource files?

Best regards and thank you,
Christian

Comment: Post a snippet of your pom.xml which shows your config.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. What are the errors? I think that package goal just do that, package, so this goal use resources filtered by 'process-resources' goal so you should build the package after files are filtered.

Comment: <resources>
      ...  
      <resource>
        <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/${tib-war}/WEB-INF</targetPath>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>

Thats the config to expand the variables in the jboss-web.xml.
When I just execute the goal 'process-resource', the right (filtered) jboss-web.xml in the target folder. After I 'package' the project the source file of the jboss-web.xml is used (with unexpanded variable names).

Comment: Sorry, the code formatting is not working...here a better link:
http://pastebin.com/FF9ihUqM